# Routing Rules icon in Microsoft ARR 3 - Server Farm Section Does not exist

Tags: load-balancing, iis-8, web-applications, arr, url-routing

I want to implement Application Load Balancing by Application Request Routing - ARR3 on IIS8. I download ARR3 Source file and install on my server. the server farm section created in my iis but when I check the ARR modules it includes Cacheing, Health Test, Load Balance, Monitoring and Management, Proxy and Server Affinity. as I see in the educational video and document in must include another module by the name of Routing Rules but it didn't. 
anybody know how could I add this feature in my server farm?
.
.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oook :)
I found my answer so soon.
I must install Url rewrite too.
when you install it, routing rules automatically add to your server farm features.